# Set-Acl with Append

Tags: powershell, acl, access-control

How can I append the ACL's of one folder to another with PowerShell?

I tried with `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl`, but "when the commands complete, the security descriptors .. are identical."

This causes my `\\dest\share` below to lose `dest\Administrators: Full Control` and other default share permissions.

`Get-Acl '\\source\share' | Set-Acl '\\dest\share'`

> [Set-Acl - Examples | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-6#examples)
>
> **Example 1: Copy a security descriptor from one file to another**
>
> ```
> $DogACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Dog.txt"
> Set-Acl -Path "C:\Cat.txt" -AclObject  $DogACL
> ```
>
> These commands copy the values from the security descriptor of the
>   Dog.txt file to the security descriptor of the Cat.txt file. When the
>   commands complete, the security descriptors of the Dog.txt and Cat.txt
>   files are identical.

How can I append the ACL's of `\\source\share` to `\\dest\share`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the extra ACL's instead of replace them, you'll have to modify the destination ACL before setting it.

Here's a how I would set things up to test it before trying it on live shares:

```
# Make folders and shares on the machine you'd like to test on
New-Item -Path C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\Share1 -Type Directory -Force
New-Item -Path C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\Share2 -Type Directory -Force
New-SmbShare -Path "C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\Share1" -Name SourceShare
New-SmbShare -Path "C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\Share2" -Name DestinationShare
```

Now, take a moment to go manually make a change to the ACL's on the shares so you can tell if it works when copying it over to from source to destination. Then continue below:

```
# Set network share path variables
$SourceShare = "\\GLaDOS\SourceShare"
$DestinationShare = "\\GLaDOS\DestinationShare"

# Set ACL variables
$SourceAcl = Get-Acl $SourceShare
$DestinationAcl = Get-Acl $DestinationShare

# Add all the source ACL's to the destination ACL
$SourceAcl.Access | foreach {$DestinationAcl.AddAccessRule($_)}

# Invoke the command on the computer using local path since network path does not seem to work    
Invoke-Command -ComputerName GLaDOS -ScriptBlock {$LocalPath = (Get-SmbShare -Name DestinationShare).Path ; Set-Acl $LocalPath $Using:DestinationAcl}
```

Obviously you'll want to replace the TestUser and GLaDOS with username and computername respectively.

---

P.S. Before I used `Invoke-Command` I tried a less complicated option and got an authentication error:

```
PS C:\> Set-Acl $DestinationShare $DestinationAcl
Set-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

Still haven't figured out that one. I should have all the permissions needed.